# Is there a performance difference between ES Modules and CommonJS in Node 16+?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I am working with a project that still transpiles TS into commonJS for running on Node. Now that node has started to toward ES Modules, is there a performance advantage to migrating away from commonjs? Or is the difference literally superficial?

I know in previous versions native ESM was not supported so the older answers and other questions seem to be outdated. Because of this I can't seem to find a good answer.

Comment: I would really like to know this too

Comment: Given the more readable syntax, ES modules offer better developer performance.

Comment: @Bergi please realise that your comment does not relate to the question. They use TypeScript -- hence, they always write ES Modules only. The question is whether to tune the transpiler to output CommonJS or ES Modules. It does not affect the developer performance.

Answer (score 1):

> CommonJS loads modules synchronously, ES modules are asynchronous.
>
> One of the limitations of using require() is that it loads modules
> synchronously. This means that modules are loaded and processed one by
> one.
>
> As you might have guessed, this can pose a few performance issues for
> large-scale applications that hundreds of modules. In such a case,
> import might outperform require() based on its asynchronous behavior.
>
> However, the synchronous nature of require() might not be much of a
> problem for a small-scale application using a couple of modules.

The above text is quoted directly from https://blog.logrocket.com/commonjs-vs-es-modules-node-js/

Comment: Not an answer :(